# Ruby on Rails App Not Connecting FTP and MySql on server but works locally

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, ftp, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I am working with a Ruby on Rails app that needs to connect to an ftp server and a mysql server. The code works fine on my computer (OSX 10.8), but will not connect on my EC2 Ubuntu (12.04)Server?

I am using the mysql2 gem and net/ftp.

error for the FTP

```
501 Server cannot accept argument.
```

and this Error for the Mysql

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '{Server Name}' (110)
```

I have already tried the security groups. Not sure what the next step is.

Thanks for your help in advance.

UPDATE:

FTP needed to be passive, and the MySql DB was blocking my ip .

Comment: I think you would need to show your connection strings to help troubleshoot your problem. Often times they are specific to your host, so you may want to check with them.

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql database from your Ubuntu command line?
Also are you able to simply do ftp to the ftp server from Ubuntu command prompt?